# How to communicate on Bluetooth with low and predictable latency?

Tags: android, bluetooth, kernel, android-bluetooth

I am looking for a way to send a notification from an Android phone to another via Bluetooth, with low and (more importantly) predictable latency. More specifically:

- t1 := the time when the sender's kernel sends my notification to the BT controller
- t2 := the time when the receiver's kernel receives it from the BT controller
- t2-t1 should be near constant (i.e. low variance, within 1-2ms range)
- Exchanging information beforehand (such as establishing a connection in advance) is acceptable
- I am able to take timestamps in kernelspace, in the serial/UART driver code

How can I do this with Bluetooth on an Android phone (if it is at all possible)?

P.S. I don't mind using Bluetooth HCI commands, or dealing with native C/C++ code, kernel code or driver code.